# How do you derive the new mean and variance when two gaussian functions are multiplied together?

Tags: probability-distributions, gaussian

I'm trying to understand the contents of this [web-page](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/sasp/Product_Two_Gaussian_PDFs.html) which suggest that multiplying two Gaussian functions together produce a new Gaussian function with a new mean and variance.

Say I have the two following Gaussian functions:

[image]

The web-page state that the new mean and variance to be:

[image]

I start by multiplying the two functions, but I am unable to get the result into Gaussian form such that I can extract the new mean and variance. Any tips on how these values were calculated?

Comment: I think you should consider $\log Z = \log X + \log Y$

Comment: Not sure I'm following.